# WPF MVVM ListView does not update!

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, datagrid, prism

I'm using Prism v4 , and MVVM.
In my viewmodel i have:

```
private TB_COMPANY tb;
    public TB_COMPANY Tb {
        get {
            return this.tb;
        }

        private set {
            if ( this.tb != value ) {
                this.tb = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Tb);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my Page, i have a datagrid (i tried with a listview too, don't work!):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Tb.TB_ADDRESS.RL_ADDRESS_PHONE}" .../>
```

RL_ADDRESS_PHONE is a list of phones of the company...
So, in some moment i add phone to the list:

```
private void MyCommand() 
{
    ...
    Tb.TB_ADDRESS.RL_ADDRESS_PHONE.Add(
        new RL_ADDRESS_PHONE
        {
            TB_PHONE = new TB_PHONE 
                       { 
                           NU_PHONE = _txtTelefone, 
                           ST_TYPE = _txtTipoTelefone 
                       }
         });
    ...
}
```

But nothing happens to the UI...
But in the Debug, the list is fullfiled....
What should i do to update the UI?

Comment: Holy crap... I hope you have no control OVER_YOUR_MODEL_CLASS_AND_PROPERTY_NAMES.  Whoever does, hit them with a copy of the Framework Guidelines.

Comment: I don't get it? What do you mean?

Comment: @Renalf: We need to see the definition of your RL_ADDRESS_PHONE property as well as the contents of your RaisePropertyChanged method. Also, what Will means is that ALL_CAPS_PROPERTIES is generally considered to make the code less readable. There is a framework development guideline document published by Microsoft that has their best practices in it and this is one that is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... I've done a workaround... Now it'll work

Comment: @Renanlf: Do you mean you fixed the issue you described above? If so, would you mind posting what you fixed so that it can benefit others?

Comment: For some reason, the WCF was turning my lists into arrays, and not an observablecollection. I fixed it to be all observablecollections and it worked!

Comment: @Renanlf: so that would be Femaref's answer you'd want to mark as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RL_ADDRESS_PHONE` property of `TB_ADDRESS` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well. If it is a `List`, you should use `ObservableCollection` which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which is necessary for the behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Also, as a piece of advise - have a look into the design guidelines and naming convention of the C# language, you can find it in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke%28vs.71%29.aspx) (while it says .net 1.1, it still applies for any following versions of the framework).

Answer (score 2):

Does your binding work? Have you checked the Output window? Are all the properties on your binding path public? Needs more code.

All property notifications aside: If your binding finds the `ObservableCollection` it **will** update if you add objects. So i think you might be using a field or a non-public property somewhere on the path.

If this is not the case make sure you do not overwrite the reference to the `ObservableCollection` unless you have a proper `PropertyChanged` notification in place. (You should implement that interface (`INotifyPropertyChanged`) in every class on your binding path since every overwritten reference that the view is not notified of will break your update).

Comment: The object TB_COMPANY comes from a WCF service, and it's a POCO from Entitys Framework.

I have set the Service to put all collections as ObservableCollection

Comment: And yes, all bindings works... I have a lot of other bindings for my Tb property, and all of then work... Like:  <TextBox x:Name="txtNome" Width="562" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding Tb.DS_COMPANY}" MaxLength="80" />

Comment: Added another source for problems. Also: Still needs more code.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the use of a WCF service.  Is it possible that your observable collection is being created on a different thread to the UI thread.  If this is the case you UI will not be able to bind to it.  Bea Stollnitz discusses issues with cross thread binding on her blog here -> http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=34.

You should be able to get round it by invoking the creation of the observable collection onto the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks... But that's not the case =/